# A weird issue on a page I'm designing

Tags: css

I've designing a page for a site of mine, but I'm getting a strange issue with the following code.

```
<section id="struttura" class="inner">
<div class="content">
....
</div>
</section>
<section id="solitaguida" class="inner">
<div class="content">
...
</div>
</section>

section .inner { margin-top: 1.5em; }
div .inner { padding-top: 1.5em; }
```

AS you can see I use the .inner class in the section item, but for some reason also the div .inner is read adding double the space.

I can't understand the reason.

Is the "section" item treated as a div.

Comment: Wouldn't that question belong in StackOverflow?

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter so does this mean I can't have 1.5 at all?

Comment: The support is not that bad for rem units actually. No IE8 and no Opera but the rest works. http://caniuse.com/rem

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what the question is, but yes, this should be on StackOverflow. Ideally, you'd also post your code with a link to JSFiddle for us to take a look at in-browser.

Comment: And scott has a good point...do you really mean `section .inner` or did you mean `section.inner`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your'e CSS is not specific enough from the sound of things. You need to **remove the spaces in the selectors**.

```
section .inner { margin-top: 1.5em; }
```

All `<section>` tags followed by a class of inner. Add the `margin` to  *anything* within a `<section>` which has the "inner" class.

```
div .inner { padding-top: 1.5em; }
```

All `<div>` tags followed by a class of inner. Add the `padding` to  *anything* within a `<div>` which has the "inner" class.

So with that in mind... anything with an "inner" class inside both a `<section>` and `<div>` tag will have both the `margin` and `padding` applied to it.

Using your current CSS, you're basically writing....

```
<section class="inner">
<div></div>
</section>
```

which translates to....

```
<section style="margin-top: 1.5em;">
<div style="margin-top: 1.5em, padding-top:1.5em;"></div>
</section>
```

What I think you *want* is...

```
section.inner { margin-top: 1.5em; }
```

**Only** `<section>` with a class of inner.

and

```
div.inner { padding-top: 1.5em; }
```

**Only** `<div>` with a class of inner.

The spaces in the selectors are causing them to be far more global than it appears you want.